# Inset PNG into Body of Outlook Email with Python

Tags: python, outlook

The goal of the below script is trying to take a Table from an Excel file and paste the image into a body of an outlook email. Currently the below is doing everything except the table is pasting as a red x. This code works if I am pasting the image with a file path of my Desktop computer but I need to paste using a shared file path.

This is my current python script that produces an email with a red X

```
file = r'X:\Stephanie Roth\Data_Releases\GDP\GDP_Deflator.xlsm'
file_png = r'X:\Stephanie Roth\Data_Releases\Python\GDP_Deflator.png'
sub = "Macro1.RefreshData"
run_macro(file, sub)

#Step 2 Copy Table
workbook_path = get_file_location(file)
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(workbook_path)
sheet = wb.Sheets['Table']
#excel.Visible = True
copyrange = sheet.Range('D6:G40')
copyrange.CopyPicture(Appearance=1, Format=2)
ImageGrab.grabclipboard().save(file_png)
excel.Quit()

#create outlook email and insert excel content 
image_path = get_file_location(file_png)
html_body = """
    <div>
        Test <br><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src={}></img>
    </div>
"""
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')  
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.To = "myemail@gmail.com"
message.Subject = "Refreshed GDP Deflator Data"
message.HTMLBody = html_body.format(image_path)
message.Display()
message.Save()  
message.Send()
```

Comment: It is not clear how exactly you are inserting the image. What is the final HTML?

Comment: I believe this part of the code is inserting the image into the body of email.. message.HTMLBody = html_body.format(image_path)

Comment: So the HTML body is referencing a local file? Of course it won't work. You need t oadd the image as an attachment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67204814/332059